# If I insert text before playing a sound, why do I not see the text inserted until the sound finishes?

Tags: display

I'm trying to, in a buffer, insert some text, then play a sound. Sample code is as follows:

```
(progn (insert "this won't be inserted until after the sound")
       (play-sound '(sound :file "/home/zck/Documents/countdown.el/Ovation-Mike_Koenig-1061486511.wav")))
```

Put the path to a wav file in the argument to `play-sound`. I've tried multiple files, but [this](http://soundbible.com/1647-Ovation.html) is the one I'm using.

The result is that I hear the sound, *then* the text is inserted. How can I invert that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs normally doesn't render the screen until it's waiting for input. From the [Emacs redisplay documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Forcing-Redisplay.html#Forcing-Redisplay):

> Emacs normally tries to redisplay the screen whenever it waits for input.

Since `play-sound` blocks, Emacs doesn't wait for input until the sound ends, so it won't render the screen with the inserted text until `play-sound` returns.

Since we don't want to wait for input between inserting the text and playing the sound, we can explicitly call `redisplay` to force Emacs to redraw the screen.

```
(progn (insert "this won't be inserted until after the sound")
       (redisplay)
       (play-sound '(sound :file "/home/zck/Documents/countdown.el/Ovation-Mike_Koenig-1061486511.wav")))
```

This has the desired behavior of seeing the text inserted before the sound starts.