# Displaying buffer modification before end of function

Tags: redisplay

I notice that Emacs waits for the end of a function to actually display the buffer modifications the function has produced. For instance, if a function looks like this:

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "Hello world!")
  (function-with-rather-long-execution-time))
```

Then, Emacs waits until the end of the execution of the whole function before displaying "Hello world!", whereas I would like the string to appear right away, before the execution of `function-with-rather-long-execution-time`. Is there a solution ?

Comment: Try to put `(sit-for 0)` behind `(insert "Hello world!")`.

Comment: That didn't work for me, but (redisplay t) did

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I insert text before playing a sound, why do I not see the text inserted until the sound finishes?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17773/if-i-insert-text-before-playing-a-sound-why-do-i-not-see-the-text-inserted-unti)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `(sit-for 0)` or `(redisplay t)`.

The help for `redisplay`:

> Perform redisplay.
>   Optional arg FORCE, if non-nil, prevents redisplay from being
>   preempted by arriving input, even if ‘redisplay-dont-pause’ is nil.
>   If ‘redisplay-dont-pause’ is non-nil (the default), redisplay is never
>   preempted by arriving input, so FORCE does nothing.
>
> Return t if redisplay was performed, nil if redisplay was preempted
>   immediately by pending input.

Example:

```el
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "Hello world!")
  (redisplay t)
  ;; Stuff with rather long execution time:
  (let ((end-time (time-add (current-time) '(0 10 0 0))))
    (while (time-less-p (current-time) end-time))))
```

Both methods, `(redisplay t)` and `(sit-for 0)` were tested with:

> GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.22.28) of 2018-05-28

Comment: Thanks, `(redisplay t)` worked fine! For some reason `(sit-for 0)` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The long running function will have to do something : like https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Forcing-Redisplay.html#Forcing-Redisplay